# Registry cleaners from a programmer point of view

Tags: registry

every now and then I hear about "registry cleaner", "orphaned registry entries" and other things like this. I'm a C#/.NET programmer and I know basic things about registry, I've been using registry in my apps and so on. The problem is I can't connect those two 'points of view' on windows registry.

Can anyone explain what are 'orphaned registry entries', how does that software detect them, what impact does that have on windows performance?

Long story short: are those registry cleaners worth anything? Or it's just a hoax - a catch for 'power users'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "orphaned registry entry" would be something in the registry that isn't used any more, or doesn't work because something that it depends on doesn't exist. It could for example be an entry that tells windows to run an application at startup, and that application is not installed any more.

The usefulness of a registry cleaner would depend a lot on the state of your registry. If you install a lot of crappy programs that misuse the registry or doesn't clean up properly when uninstalled, you could have use for a cleanup. If the registry for example contains a startup entry for a program that doesn't exist any more, cleaning out that entry would make your computer boot just slightly faster. If there is a lot of junk in the registry a cleanup could definitely make a noticable difference.

If you are careful with what you install, the use of a registry cleaner would be less. You might not get any noticable performance difference.

There is of course also a small risk that a registry cleanup program removes something that it shouldn't, so you should be careful when you pick what registry cleaner to use.

Comment: That's what I expected those kind of programs try to do. How can they tell if the registry entry is orphaned? If I create an entry at HKLM\Software\MyCompany\Notes and use registry as a kind of notepad then is this kind of entry an orphan or not? Or maybe they have a database of possibilities with common software?

Comment: @kubal5003: That would not be considered as something that could be cleaned out. A registry cleaner can only remove entries that it knows about already, i.e. entries from known pograms, or entries that have a special meaning for the system.